# Java: Most efficient method to iterate over all elements in a org.w3c.dom.Document?

Tags: java, xml, dom, iteration

What is the most efficient way to iterate through all DOM elements in Java?

Something like this but for every single DOM elements on current `org.w3c.dom.Document`?

```
for(Node childNode = node.getFirstChild(); childNode!=null;){
    Node nextChild = childNode.getNextSibling();
    // Do something with childNode, including move or delete...
    childNode = nextChild;
}
```

Comment: Recursive invocation of Node.getChildNodes? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes%28%29

Comment: I think it's interesting that the question asked the _most efficient_ method to iterate over all elements of a `Document`, but none of the answers did any tests of efficiency, and the only mention of efficiency was "I think" or similar surmises.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Basically you have two ways to iterate over all elements:

**1. Using recursion** (the most common way I think):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("document.xml"));
    doSomething(document.getDocumentElement());
}

public static void doSomething(Node node) {
    // do something with the current node instead of System.out
    System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            //calls this method for all the children which is Element
            doSomething(currentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Avoiding recursion** using `getElementsByTagName()` method with `*` as parameter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("document.xml"));
    
    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            // do something with the current element
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
        }
    }
}
```

I think these ways are both efficient.

Comment: Passing the iteration index as an argument to the recursive function, you can made it tail-recursive, which is optimized by compiler, to avoid stack overflow.

Comment: I think it's too late to avoid stack overflow. You're already here.

Comment: What makes you think that the creation of a node list for the whole document is efficient? This means almost copying the whole document. Or is there some kind of delayed evaluation hidden in `NodeList` optimizing sequential calls to `item`?

Comment: @ceving NodeList is an interface.  Implementations are free to do advanced things.  The item(n) implementation in org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode includes a cache but it is used to speed up the lookup, not to save memory.

Comment: Go with answer #2 but change the for loop to read:
for (int i = 0, len = nodeList.getLength(); i < len; i++)

Answer (score 37):

`for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)`

change to

`for (int i = 0, len = nodeList.getLength(); i < len; i++)`

to be more efficient.

The second way of javanna answer may be the best as it tends to use a flatter, predictable memory model.

Comment: You need at least 50 rep score to comment. I had the same problem and answered because I couldn't comment. Have some upvote-aid ;)

Comment: The avoiding recursion solution above prevents the program from using more stack memory based on the data.  Each step in recursion pushes more data into the stack.

Answer (score 2):

I also stumbled over this problem recently. Here is my solution.
I wanted to avoid recursion, so I used a while loop.

Because of the adds and removes in arbitrary places on the list,
I went with the `LinkedList` implementation.

```java
/* traverses tree starting with given node */
  private static List<Node> traverse(Node n)
  {
    return traverse(Arrays.asList(n));
  }

  /* traverses tree starting with given nodes */
  private static List<Node> traverse(List<Node> nodes)
  {
    List<Node> open = new LinkedList<Node>(nodes);
    List<Node> visited = new LinkedList<Node>();

    ListIterator<Node> it = open.listIterator();
    while (it.hasNext() || it.hasPrevious())
    {
      Node unvisited;
      if (it.hasNext())
        unvisited = it.next();
      else
        unvisited = it.previous();

      it.remove();

      List<Node> children = getChildren(unvisited);
      for (Node child : children)
        it.add(child);

      visited.add(unvisited);
    }

    return visited;
  }

  private static List<Node> getChildren(Node n)
  {
    List<Node> children = asList(n.getChildNodes());
    Iterator<Node> it = children.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
      if (it.next().getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        it.remove();
    return children;
  }

  private static List<Node> asList(NodeList nodes)
  {
    List<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>(nodes.getLength());
    for (int i = 0, l = nodes.getLength(); i < l; i++)
      list.add(nodes.item(i));
    return list;
  }
```