# Iterate over XML tag using java

Tags: java, xml, domparser

Hi I have one XML file which contains following form of tags

```
<values>
   <value>Yes</value>
   <value>No</value>
   <value>other</value>
</values>
```

what I need to do with is, I need iterate over these tags and get the values. I am using DOM parser technique to parse the XML file. How do I do this.

**Note** : `<value>` tag can increase in number. According to that, with the help of Java code I would be able to get all values from `<value>` tag .

This is what I did.

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("values");
for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < nodeList.getLength(); temp1++) 
{
    Node node = nodeList.item(temp1);

    if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
         Element element = (Element)node;
         String value = element.getElementsByTagName("value").item(0).getTextContent();
         System.out.println("Values are:::" + value);
    }

}
```

Comment: have you coded anything ?

Comment: Please ask google  before posting in stackoverflow e.g. `how to parse XML using DOM parser in Java`

Comment: Don't post code in comments, edit your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386991/java-most-efficient-method-to-iterate-over-all-elements-in-a-org-w3c-dom-docume

Comment: @nafas I checked that also but I did not find this kind of scenario

Comment: Dont you just need 1 more loop? As of now you have `element.getElementsByTagName("value").item(0)`... just loop through those results like you do above and get each elements text content, right?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Please refer updated below code:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("values");

for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < nodeList.getLength(); temp1++) 
{
     Node node = nodeList.item(temp1);

     if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
     {

      String value = node.getTextContent();

      System.out.println("value:::"+value);

     }

}
```

This will give you the output as:

`Yes 
 No
 Other`