# How to print ACTUAL textContent in node using Document in Java

Tags: java, xml

I am using iterate over all nodes in xml document:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
    .newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File(path)); //path is path to xml document

NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        // do something with the current element
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName() + ": " + node.getTextContent());
    }
}
```

Source: [Java: Most efficient method to iterate over all elements in a org.w3c.dom.Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386991/java-most-efficient-method-to-iterate-over-all-elements-in-a-org-w3c-dom-docume)

And I want print text of each node.

When I call `node.getTextContent()` it return me string of all childs in this node.

Example:

```
<chanel>
   <car>opel</car>
   <color>orange</color>
</chanel>
```

**Output**:

```
chanel: opel
        orange
car: opel
color: orange
```

But.. item chanel does't have a text opel and orange? How to print only text in actual node?

**Like this:**

chanel: null
car: opel
color: orange

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

1 for each element => take the children

```
                 the_node.getChildNodes()
```

2 then test if of type Text

3 then getTextContent ()

another solution: use XPath