# Tag names are missing in the XML parsed except the root element

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am reading a dynamic XML file (without any known structure) and putting the relevant tag name and value to a hashmap (ex: `metadata<tagName, Value>` ).

My issue here is, I can not get the tagName but it only adds the root tagName and all the values of entire xml.

my XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <form kwf="VARA">
                <sec1>
                    <docID>2d2c5bf209b79d8b1a1f840ce4ce4030e66a76d6</docID>
                    <qrCode>xx.jpg</qrCode>
                    <title>NOOO FORM NAME</title>
                    <ELO_VARAFNAME>NO</ELO_VARAFNAME>
                    <ELO_VARALNAME>NAME</ELO_VARALNAME>   
                    <ELO_VARAEMAIL>noname@gmail.com</ELO_VARAEMAIL>
                    <ELO_VARAORBEONDOCID>2d2c5bf209b79d8b1a1f840ce4ce4030e66a76d6</ELO_VARAORBEONDOCID>
                </sec1>
            </form>
```

My Code is:

```
public static Map<String,String> getMetaDataFromOrbeonXML(File fXmlFile) throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException
  {
    Map metaData = new HashMap();
    String formName="";
    String docID = "";
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

       doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

       System.out.println("Root element :" +        doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("form");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
              Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

             docID = eElement.getElementsByTagName("docID").item(0).getTextContent();
                metaData.put("docID", docID);
                metaData.put("appName", APP_NAME);
                metaData.put(eElement.getTagName(), eElement.getTextContent());

                System.out.println("META DATA MAP: "+ metaData.toString());

        }
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      return metaData;
 }
```

And the out put is:

```
{form=                  2d2c5bf209b79d8b1a1f840ce4ce4030e66a76d6
                        xx.jpg
                        NOOO FORM NAME
                        NO
                        NAME   
                        noname@gmail.com
                        2d2c5bf209b79d8b1a1f840ce4ce4030e66a76d6

                , docID=2d2c5bf209b79d8b1a1f840ce4ce4030e66a76d6, appName=VIRGINAUSI, formName=AITSLForm}
```

Tag names are missing in the map except the root element. Please help !

Answer (score 0):

The code above correctly adds 2 entries in the map. The first entry, maps element `Form` to it's text content (which is the collection of the text content of all it's descendant nodes).

If you want to access the descendant nodes you'll need to use `eElement.getChildNodes()` and iterate over the `NodeList` returned.

This might be useful:
[Java: Most efficient method to iterate over all elements in a org.w3c.dom.Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386991/java-most-efficient-method-to-iterate-over-all-elements-in-a-org-w3c-dom-docume)